# FreeBSD to Windows using Cygwin

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin, fortran, freebsd

I have a C & Fortran Codes developed in FreeBSD and I want to run that on my windows system. So I am using Cygwin as an Alternative.
Apart from the codes there is also a Makefile and I had tried and made some changes in Makefile. Now makefile runs perfectly but at a point in makefile it gives me loads of errors related to Fortran and Lapack libraries.
I have checked my libraries and both of them are present in my system.
After referring the relevant questions from the forum, I have tried and used the many options. But that did not work.
And I am new to this Makefile stuff.
Please do help me to sort out these errors.

---

Following is the Makefile

---

```
#BASE_DIR=..
STD_LIB= -lm -llapack -lblas -lgcc  -lgfortran
#PROF_LIB=-lm_p -llapack_p -lblas_p -lg2c_p -L/usr/local/lib/gcc46 -lgfortran
#PROF=-pg

:if empty(PROF)
LDFLAGS=$(STD_LIB)
:else
LDFLAGS=$(PROF_LIB)
:endif


#LDFLAGS+=-L $(TOOL_DIR)/trapfpe -ltrapfpe

#test::
#   echo LDFLAG=$(LDFLAGS)

CC=/usr/bin/gcc
FC=/usr/bin/gfortran
CFLAGS= -g -ggdb -O3 -ffast-math -I -Wall $(PROF)
#CFLAGS= -g -ffast-math -I -Wall $(PROF)
FFLAGS= -g -I -Wall $(PROF) -fbounds-check
COMMON_OBJS=phase_unwrapping-lib.o matrix.o splotlib.o args_lib.o
UNWRAP_TOOL=rot_comp_unwrap
SUB=res_pos
ALL=$(UNWRAP_TOOL)
WORK=$(ALL)
WORK+=poisson_test boundary_search clustering band_matrix

default:: ctags $(WORK)
all:: $(ALL)

ctags::tags
tags:$(WORK:C/$/.c/) $(SUB:C/$/.c/)
ctags -w $ $^
#   ctags -w $ (.ALLSRC)

GA_OBJS=res_pos.o ga-core.o ga-fit.o data.o
CLUSTERING_OBJS=clustering.o
BOUNDARY_SUB_OBJS=poisson_enclosed_Neumann.o intlin.o solve_flux_eps_least_norm.o        band_matrix.o
BOUNDARY_OBJS=boundary_search.o $(BOUNDARY_SUB_OBJS)

SRCS=rot_comp_unwrap.c clustering.c boundary_search.c poisson_test.c res_pos.c band_matrix.c


rot_comp_unwrap:rot_comp_unwrap.o $(GA_OBJS) $(CLUSTERING_OBJS) $(BOUNDARY_OBJS)   $(COMMON_OBJS)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(.TARGET) $(LDFLAGS) $(.ALLSRC)
res_pos:res_pos.c ga-core.o ga-fit.o data.o
$(CC) -o $@ -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^
#   $(CC) -o $(.TARGET) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(.ALLSRC)

poisson_test:poisson_test.o poisson_enclosed_Neumann.o intlin.o
$(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^
#   $(CC) -o $(.TARGET) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(.ALLSRC)

boundary_search:boundary_search.c $(BOUNDARY_SUB_OBJS) $(COMMON_OBJS)
$(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) -O3 -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
#   $(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) -O3 -o $(.TARGET) $(LDFLAGS) $(.ALLSRC)

band_matrix:band_matrix.c $(COMMON_OBJS)
$(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) -ffast-math -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
#   $(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) -ffast-math -o $(.TARGET) $(LDFLAGS) $(.ALLSRC)
clustering:clustering.c $(COMMON_OBJS)
$(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) -ffast-math -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
#   $(CC) -DMAIN $(CFLAGS) -ffast-math -o $(.TARGET) $(LDFLAGS) $(.ALLSRC)

clean::
rm *.o

backup::
cp -pf *.c *.F *.h *.o Makefile $(WORK) bak

depend::
mkdep ${CFLAGS} ${SRCS}
```

---

Following are the errors that i get

---

```
/usr/bin/gcc -g -ggdb -O3 -ffast-math -I -Wall  -o rot_comp_unwrap  rot_comp_unwrap.o res_pos.o ga-core.o ga-fit.o data.o clustering.o boundary_search.o poisson_enclosed_Neumann.o intlin.o solve_flux_eps_least_norm.o band_matrix.o phase_unwrapping-lib.o matrix.o splotlib.o args_lib.o
ga-core.o: In function `cpgene_':

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-core.F:93: undefined reference to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-core.F:93:(.text+0x5c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_gfortran_runtime_error_at'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-core.F:113:(.text+0x459): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-core.F:116: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_real_write'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-core.F:116: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'

ga-core.o: In function `fluct_':

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-core.F:274: undefined reference to `_gfortran_rand'

ga-core.o:/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-core.F:278: more undefined references to `_gfortran_runtime_error_at' follow

ga-fit.o: In function `gapara_':

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-fit.F:241: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_open'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-fit.F:243: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_read'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-fit.F:243: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-fit.F:243: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_read_done'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/ga-fit.F:244: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_read'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/solve_flux_eps_least_norm.F:73: undefined reference to `dgesv_'

/cygdrive/e/Lc-code1/solve_flux_eps_least_norm.F:109: undefined reference to `dgbsv_'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'rot_comp_unwrap' failed
make: *** [rot_comp_unwrap] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You dropped all external libraries from your linker flags. Add the libraries from STD_LIB to your command

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer what to do .

Comment: uncomment the line  LDFLAGS=$(STD_LIB)

Comment: I did that but its again the same errors.Is there any difference between the .f & .F extension fortran files.As my all fortran files are with .F extension.

Comment: You may try to use gfortran for compiling and linking the fortran files by using $(FC) instead of CC.

Comment: I did change $(FC) instead of $(CC) so errors related to fortran libraries vanishes and only errors related to Lapack are still there.

Comment: poisson_enclosed_Neumann.o: In function `solve_boundary_value_':
/cygdrive/e/LC-Code1/poisson_enclosed_Neumann.F:409: undefined reference to `dgels_'
solve_flux_eps_least_norm.o: In function `work_size_dgelsd_':
/cygdrive/e/LC-Code1/solve_flux_eps_least_norm.F:120: undefined reference to `dgelsd_'
cygdrive/e/LC-Code1/solve_flux_eps_least_norm.F:109:(.text+0x2c3a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `dgbsv_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'rot_comp_unwrap' failed
make: *** [rot_comp_unwrap] Error 1

Comment: googling for this symbol seems to hint that it is part of a package named opencv.